# I did not get my passport stamped in Melbourne

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, australia

I am a Indian passport holder and was going back to India when my immigration card was not checked.

How do I get my passport stamped?

Comment: Do you mean that your passport wasn't stamped when you left Australia? This is [perfectly normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passport_stamp#Australia) and shouldn't be a problem. Is there a particular reason you believe you need a stamp?

Comment: Well I thought it should be stamped as a procedure. Is that ok?? I will be travelling to Australia frequently henceforth so I don't want to have a non compliance mark on my passport. That's my concern. Yes my passport is not stamped

Comment: All visas and arrival records in Australia are electronic.  If you left via an airport, you're correctly recorded in the system, guaranteed.

Comment: @AliAwan I'll let Zach Lipton claim the credit!

Answer (score 6):

Australia [does not routinely stamp passports on exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passport_stamp#Australia). So it is perfectly normal that you left without getting an exit stamp.

They do maintain electronic entry-exit records, so they will know whether you left on time and will not hold the lack of a stamp against you.

If you're particularly concerned or think your exit may not have been recorded properly (perhaps if you entered on one passport and left on another; I'm not sure if this situation is fully accounted for), you could simply retain proof of your exit, such as your boarding pass back to India, just in case.

Comment: Most boarding passes are just pieces of print-at-home paper or even a file inside a mobile app. How could it work as proof of exit?

Comment: @JonathanReez That's the way proof generally works in many matters, it's never all or nothing but creating a document trail with many details that would be hard to fake correctly (format, codes, times, flight numbers, etc.) adds plausibility to your explanation and might shift the burden of proof. There is nothing extraordinarily complicated about a traditional boarding pass either but it's way better than nothing, especially together with other things that paint a coherent picture, like credit card receipt for charges outside the country, etc.

Comment: @JonathanReez What Relaxed said. As an example, US CBP [recommends](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1674/~/report-departure-if-entering-by-air-and-departing-by-land) documents like "foreign entry stamps in a passport, transportation tickets, pay stubs and/or other receipts" to prove exit if necessary. All of those could be faked, but they're pieces of evidence. Under normal circumstances, none of this is necessary though; the exit will have been recorded electronically.